# Html 5 regex that allow space between characters

Tags: regex, html

I need a regexp that fails in every character is outside `[a-zA-Z0-9_& -]`

Space between characters is allowed, but not empty spaces.

Allowed input examples:

`group1`, `group 1`, `Group1`, `Group1 & Group2`, `group1_Group2`, `group1_group2`

My html for input type is :

`<input type="text" required name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_& -]+"  placeholder="Group Name" />`

The problem is with the single empty space, if i put single empty space, it will pass. If i remove the space in regex pattern and become: `"[a-zA-Z0-9_&-]+"`, user won't able to input space between string, like `group 1`, how should i form the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
^(?!^ +$)([\w -&]+)$
```

[Click here for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WIFBlh/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of the string
- `(?!^ +$)` - Negative lookahead validating that the string should NOT contain ONLY 1 or more spaces between the start and end of string
- `([\w -&]+)` - Capturing 1 or more characters in the range `[a-zA-Z0-9_ &-]`
- `$` - End of the string

Answer (score 3):

Use the following pattern:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_&-]+([ ]?[a-zA-Z0-9_&-]+)*
```

This pattern matches a single term according to your definition, followed by any number of optional space and a mandatory term.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
string pattern = @"[\w&-]+[\w\s&-]*";
Regex regx = new Regex(pattern);
Match m = regx.Match("group1 & group2");
string res = m.Value;
```

Explanation:

\w: match any alphanumeric char, this will include all your char, digits and underscore

[]: defines a range of char

+: means one or more occurrence

*: means zero or more occurrences

\s: any white space

[\w&-]: means a range of alphanumeric char, or & or -

[\w&-]+: means the range should occur one or more times, so ensures that its not 
all white space

[\w\s&-]*: means zero or more occurrence of alphanumeric, whitespace, & or -